# Generate code for nested struct pointers in C

Tags: c, struct, auto-generate

I have a bunch of nested structures with arrays of pointers-to inside.
I need a tool to generate the (code) instances of the pointed-to data types.

```
typedef stuct
{
    TYPE_1  * data[5];
    int a;
}TOP_T;

typedef struct
{
    TYPE_2 * pToType1Array[2];
    char c;
}TYPE_1;

typedef struct
{
    int b;
}TYPE_2;
```

To properly use these two types, I need to create a total of 10 instances of TYPE_2 - because 5*2 - and 2 instances of TYPE_1 and then do assignment of the pointers to the instances.

```
TYPE_2 t2_0;
TYPE_2 t2_1;

TYPE_1 t1_0;
TYPE_1 t1_1;
TYPE_1 t1_2;
TYPE_1 t1_3;
TYPE_1 t1_4;

TOP_T first;

first.data[0] = &t1_0;
first.data[1] = &t1_1;
...
```

I know how to manually create the instances but would like a script/tool to do this.

I cannot use malloc.

I'm using Eclipse so I have access to the type-tree.

Now, I have to do this

```
/********* ST_CHRONO_TRACE_CONTEXT_T - one for each CHRONO_NUM_TRACE_CONTEXTS per CHRONO_NUM_SESSION_CONTEXTS session */
ST_CHRONO_TRACE_CONTEXT_T   CHRONO_TraceContext_0_0;
ST_CHRONO_TRACE_CONTEXT_T   CHRONO_TraceContext_0_1;
ST_CHRONO_TRACE_CONTEXT_T   CHRONO_TraceContext_1_0;
ST_CHRONO_TRACE_CONTEXT_T   CHRONO_TraceContext_1_1;
ST_CHRONO_TRACE_CONTEXT_T * CHRONO_TraceContext_PTRS[CHRONO_NUM_SESSION_CONTEXTS][CHRONO_NUM_TRACE_CONTEXTS] =
{
    {&CHRONO_TraceContext_0_0, &CHRONO_TraceContext_0_1},
    {&CHRONO_TraceContext_1_0, &CHRONO_TraceContext_1_1}
};
```

These definitions is what I want to auto-gen.

Comment: what do you mean by `auto-generate`? You can either use `malloc` family, build from the stack or global variables. You cannot create objects from outside.

Comment: I mean auto-generate the code, the text. I'm not allowed to use malloc. @holgac

Comment: here are some solutions for you: 1.  do it once, copy and paste. 2.  write script inside an ide like visual studio that gives you access to syntax tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot use `malloc()`-family functions, you must want either globals or stack-allocated locals.  For the rather simple case you present, you could do it semi-automatically like so:

```
TYPE_2 twos[10] = {0};
TYPE_1 ones[5] = {{0}};
TOP_T top = {{0}};

static init_pointers() {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
        top.data[i] = ones + i;
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            ones[i].pToType1Array[j] = twos + (i * 2 + j);
        }
    }
}

/* ... */

    init_pointers();
```

You can extend a function such as that to populate the non-pointer members algorithmically, too.  If you really need to generate C source code programmatically, though, then you probably need to write your own tool to do so. Such a tool could use a similar approach (pointers to array elements) to produce code that does not rely on `malloc()`, either with or without a runtime initialization function such as I present.

Comment: That's how I'm doing it now but as you guessed, my actual problem has many more nested levels and pointers to array. I was hoping there'd be a tool somewhere that someone knows about. This is definitely in the domain of code-generation.

Comment: Even so, code for a tool to generate these for you is probably more complicated than code for a function to do the initialization.  A code generator may make sense if you need to generate similar but distinct declarations for multiple source files, or if the declarations are based on some kind of external data that is subject to change, but otherwise I advise you to just stick with what you're doing now.  And as I said, if you do want a code generator, then you probably need to write it.

Comment: I don't care about the initialization. It's the generation of the global/static data structures that I'd like to automate. @john bollinger

Comment: @John, I don't understand.  If you don't care about initialization then what do you actually want to generate? The `struct` declarations?  (Based on what?)  Declarations appropriately-sized arrays of the `struct` types?

Comment: Yes the struct declarations. Here's what I have to do by hand now: (see original post)

Comment: Yes I guess I need to write my own code-generation tool, probably using Python.